# copy printing records from eventlog on server 2008 with vbscript

Tags: vbscript, windows-server-2008, wmi

I need to copy the log files that are print jobs on a windows server 2008 r2 x64 with vbscript.
The code I have now works with server 2003.When I run it on the 2008 server I don't get any errors but nothing is in the file. Here is the code

```
Set ObjFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")


StrFileName = "C:\printer report test\eventlog_norprtfl1.tsv"
strComputer = "servername"
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
& "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colLoggedEvents = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
("Select * from Win32_NTLogEvent Where LogFile='Microsoft-Windows-PrintService/Operational' and EventCode='307'") 

Set ObjFile = ObjFso.CreateTextFile(StrFileName)


For Each objItem in colLoggedEvents
objFile.WriteLine("x64^"&objItem.User&"^"&objItem.TimeWritten&"^"&objItem.Message)

Next
```

Comment: Do you get any result from your SELECT query when you run it using the Windows `wbemtest`tool?

Comment: I have never used the wbemtest tool before. But I did find Win32_NTlogEvent as a class